# Button that delete itself

Tags: python, kivy

My idea its create a order list. This have to be posible of expand or reduce if the order needed. So  I was trying how to do a button that can add a 'Box Label' to a grid, at the same time that this 'Box Label' have the property of delete by itself by a button. I tried a lot of things, but I am really new in this, so nothing work for me.

```
class OperatorWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    Window.size = (1366, 768)

    def remove_item(self):
        self.ids.parent.clear_widgets()

    def add_more(self):
        prod_addmore = self.ids.product_inputs

        product = BoxLayout(size_hint_x=1, height=30, spacing=5)

        prod = TextInput(size_hint_x=.2)
        qty = TextInput(size_hint_x=.1)
        price = TextInput(size_hint_x=.1)
        delete = Button(text='-', size_hint_x=.05)

        product.add_widget(prod)
        product.add_widget(qty)
        product.add_widget(price)
        product.add_widget(delete)

        prod_addmore.add_widget(product)
        delete.bind(on_release=self.deleting(prod_addmore, product))

    def deleting(self, prod_addmore, product):
        prod_addmore.remove_widget(product)


class OperatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return OperatorWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    oa = OperatorApp()
    oa.run()
```

**Kivy File**

```
...
           BoxLayout:
                id: products_labels
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: .45
                height: 40
                spacing: 5
                
                FlatButton:
                    size_hint_x: .2   
                    text: 'Producto'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: (.30,.30,.30,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                FlatButton:
                    size_hint_x: .1
                    text: 'Cantidad'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: (.30,.30,.30,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                FlatButton:
                    size_hint_x: .1
                    text: 'Precio'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: (.30,.30,.30,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos


                FlatButton:
                    text: '+'
                    size_hint_x: .05
                    on_release: root.add_more()
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: (.30,.30,.30,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos

        ScrollView:
            size_hint_y: .15
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True

            GridLayout:
                id: product_inputs
                size:(self.width, self.height)
                size_hint_x: .45
                spacing: 5
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 1
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_default_height: 30
                row_force_default: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://youtu.be/0TZBtpfIKcc)! For some refreshers about widgets.

Your code is fine you just need some minor adjustments here and there.

Firstly change

```
product
```

To

```
self.product
```

It always makes it easier to call functions since the self indicates ownership okay.

Secondly change this line

```
delete.bind(on_release=self.deleting(prod_addmore, product))
```

to

```
delete.bind(on_release=self.deleting)
```

the reason for the error is because of the parenthesis. And lastly

Chang this

```
def deleting(self, prod_addmore, product): 
     prod_addmore.remove_widget(product)
```

to

```
def deleting(self, widget): 
    prod_addmore = self.ids.product_inputs
    prod_addmore.remove_widget(self.product)
```

Hope this helps if you need more indept explano please let me know :)

Comment: Please change product to self.product for all the lines :)

Comment: *'the reason for the error is because of the parenthesis...'*, what if the user really want to pass some args through the function/method ? After all this will be more explicit call.